# Asymptotics of $C(x) = \int_0^x \cos(0.5\pi t^2) \ dt.$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

Consider the Fresnel integral

$$C(x) = \int_0^x \cos(0.5\pi t^2) \ dt.$$

I've calculated that, as $x\to 0$, $C(x) \sim x$ and, as $x\to\infty$, $C(x) \sim 0.5 + \frac{\sin(0.5\pi x^2)}{\pi x}$. Using these asymptotic expansions, is it possible to then deduce an approximation to $C(x)$ that is valid for all $x > 0$?

Comment: The expansion about $x=0$ will converge for all real $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$C(x) = \int_0^x \cos \left(\frac{\pi  t^2}{2}\right) \, dt$$ Use the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$C'(x)=\cos \left(\frac{\pi  x^2}{2}\right)$$  and the expansion of $\cos(y)$ is valid for all $y$. Use it, replace and integrate termwise for all $x$.
$$C(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{ \left(\frac\pi{2}\right)^{2 n}} {(4n+1)\, (2n)! }x^{2n+1}$$